# Mysterious Rails 5 API LoadError for model when posting JSON; no error when posting as form-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a namespaced model like so:

```
module A
  module B
    class C
    end
  end
end
```

in `app/models/a/b/c.rb`.

Then a Controller

```
module API
  module V2
    module B
      class CController
        include ActionController::RespondWith
        respond_to :json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

in `app/controllers/api/v2/b/c_controller.rb`

The namespaced files are autoloaded in `application.rb` via `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/*/**/"]`.

Cors is configured using:

```
config.middleware.insert_after 0, Rack::Cors, logger: Rails.logger do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: %i[get options post put patch delete]
  end
end
```

Now when I post parameters as form data to the create action, it all works fine. When I make the same request with a JSON string + Content-Type application/json header I get this error:

`LoadError:
       Unable to autoload constant C, expected 
 app/models/a/b/c.rb to define it`

Rails 5.2.0, Ruby 2.5.1

Who can help or has any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and I just successfully figured out the cause of this issue.
It's because abstract-controller tries to wrap your parameters and transform your controller class-name to model-name.
By default params-wrapper for json-requests is enabled in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb file.
But you also can disable this functionality on controller-level by defining next line in controller:

```
wrap_parameters format: []
```